# My Oledb DataAdapter.Fill code is "missing parameters"

Tags: vba, visual-studio, oledb

I am trying to set-up a login page that checks the user's credentials from an MS Access database. When I run the code, it says that the fill method needs one or more parameters. Here's the code I'm using:

```
Public Class login
Public Shared dslogin As New DataSet
Public Shared con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim da1 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

'Global variables
Public Shared currentloginID As Integer = 0
Public Shared tbusername As TextBox
Public Shared tbpassword As TextBox

Private Function OpenDBConnection1()
    Dim directory1 As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    Return "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " & directory1 & "\IEshiDBv1.accdb"
End Function

'login button
Private Sub btnLOGIN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLOGIN.Click

    Dim username As String = txtusername.Text
    Dim password As String = txtpassword.Text
    If username = "" Or password = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter log-in details")
        con.Close()
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim sqllogin As String = ("SELECT * FROM LoginRcrds WHERE LoginUserName = " & username)
        da1 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqllogin, con)
        da1.Fill(dslogin, "LoginCredentials")
        con.Close()
        Dim dtlogin As DataTable = dslogin.Tables("LoginCredentials")
        Dim rowlogin As DataRow
        For Each rowlogin In dtlogin.Rows
            If password = rowlogin("LoginPW") Then
                homepage.Show()
                Me.Hide()
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox("Incorrect log-in credentials. Please try again")
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub

'Onload subroutine
Private Sub login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = (OpenDBConnection1())
    con.Open()
End Sub
```

End Class

The error occurs at

```
da1.Fill(dslogin, "LoginCredentials")
```

and the error message says " No value given for one or more required parameters."

I read somewhere that .Fill requires three parameters: (DataSet, RecordSet, TableName). I never tried this because I don't understand what RecordSet means.

Edit: I've checked another program with a 4.0 Oledb provider and changed it to 12.0. The same error appeared. It seems that the Fill method of the DataAdapter of Oledb 12.0 requires more than 2 parameters. Can somebody explain this?

Comment: Are you sure the database is in the folder your are trying to connect to?  If it is there are you sure it has permissions to open it?

Comment: I double-checked and yes.

Comment: try moving the access database into the same directory as the app and see if it works.